# Google Sheets script for if/then statement

Tags: google-sheets

Google Sheets script for if/then statement

Can someone help me write a script for the following:

I need my Google Sheet to input "No" in column W if column J has the word "transfer" in it. Otherwise, it needs to input "N/A".

I currently have the following formula in my Google spreadsheet:

=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("transfer",J2,1)),"N/A","No")
but as you know, the formula is cleared out once it gets a new entry from the linked Google form.

Any help would be tremendously appreciated.

Comment: If this is google sheets why the Excel tag.  The languages are not the same and you will not get those that can help looking at this.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. You need to have attempted something yourself and added it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

This might restore your formula.  Try attaching it to the form submit trigger.

```
function fallingFromTheSky(e) 
{
  var row=e.range.getRow();  
  e.range.getSheet().getRange(row,23).setFormula('=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("transfer",J'+ row +',1)),"N/A","No")');
}
```